# Redirect, если количество постов в категории меньше 1

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

Я хочу редиректить пользователя назад, если он нажмет на категорию, в которой нет постов. Я пытался делать так, но что то не выходит:

```
$check = Post::all();
      if($check->count() < 1){
        return redirect()->back()->with('warning', 'No posts in this category!');
      }
```

```
$check = Category::withCount('posts')->first();
if($cheсk->posts_count < 1){
    return redirect()->back()->with('warning', 'No posts in this category!');
  }
```

```
if(Category::withCount('posts') < 1){
    return redirect()->back()->with('warning', 'No posts in this category!');
  }
```

Category model:

```
class Category extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'user_id',
        'code',
        'img'
    ];

    public function posts(){
      return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }
}
```

Кто-нибудь знает как это сделать правильно?

Comment: Не надо пользователя редиректить.Лучше либо показать, что постов нет, либо изначально показывать, что в категории ничего нет, либо дисейблить категорию и показывать, что постов 0. Но редиректить.... Вот уж пользователь будет удивлён сим поведением))

Comment: Ну вообще то так и есть). Если в категории нет постов, вместо кнопки "Open" пользователь увидит кнопку "No posts", но все же, если вставить адрес в с троку, я хотел бы редиректить). Ответ помогли найти на англоязычном StackOverflow. Приведу в комменте ниже.

Comment: Лучше пишите ответ в ответ)) Так будет лучше и кому-то поможет))

Answer (score 0):

Помог найти верное решение один пользователь из англоязычного StackOverflow. [Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65856028/redirect-if-there-are-no-posts-in-the-category-laravel/65856513#65856513) здесь вы можете найти ответ. А я приведу его применение в моем коде:

```
Route::get('/posts/{category}', [MainController::class, 'category_'])->name('category');
```

```
public function category_($category){

      $categoryName = Category::where('code', $category)->first();

      if(Category::where('code', $category)->has('posts')->count() < 1){
        return redirect()->back()->with('no-posts', $categoryName->name);
      }else{
        $category = Category::where('code', $category)->get();

        return view('category_', compact('category'));
      }
    }
```

Модель:

```
  public function posts(){
      return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }
```